# Error Installing libraries for a HMC5883L

Tags: python, pi-2, i2c, bash

I am using a HMC5883L for my Raspberry Pi and I am following [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interfacing-Digital-Compass-HMC5883L-with-Raspberr/step2/Getting-necessary-libraries-and-packages/) tutorial. But after I create the setup.env and enter `../quick2wire.env` it shows this error `bash: ../quick2wire.env: No such file or directory` I know that this means that the file wasn't found but I have followed all the steps in the tutorial so I don't know why I am gettings this error. If anyone knows another tutorial for a HMC5883L or how to fix this error I would really appreciate the help.

This is board that I am using [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00SDTFI1Q/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SDTFI1Q)

and the reference link is in the comments because I cannot put three links in (the documentation is at the bottom in the Download and Documentation)

Thank you for your time

Edit:

PWD prints `home/pi/Desktop/Compass`

and ls -l prints `total 8 
             drwxr-xr-x 7 pi pi 4096 Sep 12 00:42 code
             -rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  101 Sep 12 00:42 setup.env`

Comment: https://www.parallax.com/product/29133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial says:

`. ./quick2wire.env`

but it seems it should be saying:

`. ./setup.env`

NOTE: There is a space between the 2 periods (`.`)

All that is doing is adding the *code* (or whatever you named it) directory to your path so that Python can find the libraries it needs when you `import ...`

As these environment changes are for the life of the session only, you'll need to run that command each time you log in to your Raspberry Pi. A easier/more permanent solution is to add those 2 lines from the setup.env file to the end of your .bashrc file (in your home directory)

You should be able to check that they are set correctly with

`env | grep code`

[where 'code' is the name of the directory you have the git code in]

Comment: I have updated with the pwd and ls -l